# Only keep items from lists in a dataframe containing certain characters

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a df with one column containing a list of strings like so:

```
    'Name'     'Method'
1   foo        ['car', 'truck', 'transportation::plane']
2   bar        ['car', 'transportation::helicopter', 'boat']
3   baz        ['transportation::car', 'helicopter', 'boat']
```

I only want to keep the items in the lists under methods that contain "::" so that I get something like this:

```
    'Name'     'Method'
1   foo        ['transportation::plane']
2   bar        ['transportation::helicopter']
3   baz        ['transportation::car']
```

I know I could make a for loop to iterate through each list and then use list comprehension, but I feel like there must be a method that doesn't involve using a for loop. I tried the following

```
for j in range(len(df['Method'])):
    df['Method'].iloc[j] = [x for x in df['Method'].iloc[j] if "::" in x]
```

and it takes much longer to run than I would like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `apply`

```
In [220]: df.Method.apply(lambda x: [v for v in x if '::' in v])
Out[220]:
1         [transportation::plane]
2    [transportation::helicopter]
3           [transportation::car]
```

Details

```
In [222]: df['NMethod'] = df.Method.apply(lambda x: [v for v in x if '::' in v])

In [223]: df
Out[223]:
  Name                                   Method                       NMethod
1  foo      [car, truck, transportation::plane]       [transportation::plane]
2  bar  [car, transportation::helicopter, boat]  [transportation::helicopter]
3  baz  [transportation::car, helicopter, boat]         [transportation::car]
```

Or, use `filter`

```
In [225]: df.Method.apply(lambda x: filter(lambda v: '::' in v, x))
Out[225]:
1         [transportation::plane]
2    [transportation::helicopter]
3           [transportation::car]
Name: Method, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can using `str.contains`

```
 from itertools import compress
 import pandas as pd 

 df['Method'].apply(lambda x :list(compress(x,pd.Series(x).str.contains('::').tolist())))
```